# Why are these gravestones undated and so clean?

Tags: doctor-who

Warning, end of Doctor Who: Season 6(?) spoilers ahead.

I'm struggling to figure out why the gravestones ...

> for the Ponds are undated and so clean.

Image below

> [image]

To me it seems like they should be much older than this, and have a date on them...

I guess we need to know when they died, and when we see them. But I'm unsure of the specific dates involved. My estimations make their deaths in the early 2000s, so it's not unfeasible that the gravestones we see are in the past (relative to the audience) which might be why they are so clean....but not why they are undated as most gravestones are.

Comment: The only explanation I can think of, and there's no canon information to back this up, is that whoever buried them (and had the gravestone made) didn't know when Amy and Rory were born so couldn't provide exact dates.

Comment: One or two episodes earlier Amy also mentioned that they do not want their friends notice that they get older faster than others. So maybe they kept birthdates secret.

Comment: But a deathdate would be possible, no?

Comment: Hey, at least that tombstone is more informative than some of the ones in my family. (My sister has been doing some geneology, and she gets enormously frustrated by gravestones that say stuff like "Smith Family", with no numbers of any sort.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why they should be older. Amy and Rory were just about 30, I believe, by the time of the events of *The Angels Take Manhattan*. They were sent back to the 1930s, so would have lived for another 50 years or so in the past - putting their death dates somewhere in the 1980s or early 90s, only about 20 or so years ago.

Plus, as we learn from [the unfilmed alternative ending](http://www.guardian.co.uk/tv-and-radio/tvandradioblog/2012/oct/12/doctor-who-amy-rory-alternative-ending),

> they adopted a son,

who would have been around to keep the gravestone clean after their deaths.

As to why they're undated, what possible date could they have put on them? Born 1981, died 1988 aged 87? I doubt any mason would have agreed to carve such obvious nonsense.

Comment: They weren't necessarily sent back to 1930. The Doctor told Amy she couldn't know where (in time) she would end up.

Comment: @MrLister, that link is fairly explicit that they were.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer the why they were undated....

When you travel with the Doctor, you stop experiencing time in the normal linear fashion... as established with Rose and every other companion since, a few days could turn out to be a year and a couple of years may end up being just an hour or two (in comparison of course to someone who was born around the same timeline as you and does in fact NOT travel in time).

Yes basically, we can assume thats cos of the wibbly wobbly timey wimey nature of the universe.

I think Rory and Amy would just want their future generations/friends/companions to know that they lived a full life, and in human years had experienced 82 and 87 years of aging together. That may make more sense than writing "Rory - Born 1989 : Died 1963 - Aged 82)

On that note, I think it kind of makes me sad that Amy had to wait 5 years for Rory to get transported back in time by the angels to be with her. I guess the only way she could tell the Doctor that 'Yes, I waited for him, but I found him and we lived happily ever after' would be the 5 years age difference between the two... Knowing Amy of course I bet she didnt let Rory forget that :)

Comment: Was there really an implication that Amy waited for Rory? Their different ages at death is more simply explained by Amy dying some years after Rory.

Comment: @Martha you are correct; in Blink it was established that an angel sends people back the same distance in time, or at least multiple attacks within a few days send people back to very similar times. This was explained when the Doctor and Martha met Billy Shipton, all of whom had been sent to the same time. The Doctor denies this fact to Amy, but it's more likely he was lying to keep her from leaving than had been lying before and experienced a massive coincidence. (River's reaction lends credence to the lying theory as well).